# Computing the power function in O(1)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have written a function that computes pow(a,b) in O(logb).

```
double pow(double a, int b){
  double res=1;
    while(b>0){
        if (b%2==1){
            res=res*a;
        }
      b=b>>1;
      a=a*a;

    }
    return res;
}
```

I have stumbled upon the question if it would be possible to write a function pow(double a, double b) in `O(1)` time. Yet I have not found an answer.

Comment: If it was possible, don't you think standard implementations would use such a method?

Comment: Assuming IEEE754, we have 64 bit for double, i. e. 2^64 values, two parameters, 2^65 combinations. As we have a finite set of input, we *always* are O(1)...

Comment: To say anything meaningful about computational complexity, you need to define what are the basic operations you're counting, and in terms of what variable.

Comment: As Aconcagua noted you have a finite set of inputs. So you could use a (rather large!) lookup table.

Comment: When `a` is known at compile time you can just compute it at compile time.

Comment: You must choose between `double b` and `int b`; these are different problems.

Comment: @Aconcagua Well, (2^64)^2 is 2^128 for two parameters, but we have a lot of repeated NaNs and INFs.. . ;)

Comment: @Bob__ Huh, of course it is - seems as if I haven't been fully awake when writing the comment! Luckily, the actual value is not of importance for the statement itself...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't allow yourself the use of the standard pow/exp/log functions nor precomputed tables, but allow floating-point multiplies, then your solution is optimal (constant time is impossible).

Answer (score 1):

If you allow a few restrictions on the parameters (`a` positive, `a` and `b` doubles) and on the result (a double) you could use

```
exp(b * log(a))
```

This will often not be exact, even when an exact result is possible. In my Borland Delphi days, I coded a similar routine but used base `2` rather than the base `e` that is often used. That improved both the accuracy and the speed of the code, since the CPU works in base `2`. But I have no idea how to do that in C++.

Comment: That is not O(1) though... Is it?

Comment: @Ash: Since `a` and `b` are doubles, the `exp` and `log` functions are (mostly) handled by the CPU and use a limited number of CPU cycles, and thus are order one. The advantage of your code is that it more often returns an exact answer.

Comment: @Ash: I should add that your code also allows `a` to be zero or negative.

Comment: I am not OP ;) But I'm very skeptical about your explanation... Can you please add some references? Maybe we can get close to `O(1)` but theoretically, I think that the higher bound would be logarithmic...

Comment: Okay, this post seems rather convincing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317414/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-log-function , it indicaters thay it won't be `O(1)` for arbitray precision... But it is to be expected I guess, and OP's question isn't about that... Leaving it here in case someone has the same question as me.

Comment: @Ash: You are correct that the log function is not O(1) for *arbitrary precision*... but that is why I emphasized that your parameters are *doubles*. (I just added that to my main answer, copied from my previous comment.) For the limited number of bits, the log and exp approximation operations become O(1).

Comment: @Ash: from an Intel manual you can know the maximum number of cycles, which should be on the order of 100.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write one with precompute. Compute all possible power into a table and loop up when necessary. Indeed this method works for many problems.

Now, assume that you have found a new algorithm other than the table look up and the complexity of the new algorithm is O(1). Now a result;

- The complexity of addition is O(1) by x^b * x^c = x^(a+c). calculate and take log base b, especially if base 2.

So you can reduce almost every arithmetic operation by using your new algorithm.

as Yvies said this is optimal.