# What is the time complexity of log10 function in cmath?

Tags: c++, cmath

What is the time complexity of log10 function in cmath ? 
Its nowhere mentioned on the internet. Does anyone know for sure ?

Later edit:
My initial question was if the following code is faster.

```
int numOfDigits(int n) {
  return (int)log10(n) + 1;
}
```

than this

```
int numOfDigits(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  while(n) {
    count ++;
    n /= 10;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

i know for sure that the second function time complexity is O(log(n)).
What's the time complexity of the first function.

Comment: I expect in a typical implementation it is bounded by a constant time, barring external factors such as cache conflicts. The overall algorithm is to separate the exponent and significand of the floating-point operand, multiply the exponent by a conversion factor, evaluate a fixed (and highly engineered) polynomial to get the log of the significand, and add them.

Comment: That's probably because there is no requirement imposed by standard, so it's entirely up to implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the complexity of the log function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317414/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-log-function)

Comment: I read that post but it doesnt answer my question. I wanted something more exact so to speak.

Comment: Is it ok to assume that its takes O(1) time ?

Comment: @michael_blaze You can dig up implementations used by your (or other major) compilers, and analyze the complexity of the code.

Comment: @michael_blaze: We cannot tell you if it is okay to assume because you have not specified what is at stake or what C++ implementation you are using. If you want your program to perform pleasantly, sure it is okay to assume. If you want to guarantee real-time control of life-critical machinery, it is not okay to assume.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil to be honest i feel like i made this question sound really important )). Well its "nothing at stake".I just asked this question out of curiosity because one of friends wanted a faster way to get the number of digits and i came up with "log10" approuch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard does not specify complexity requirement for the `log10` function.

However, I would expect a reasonable implementation to have constant complexity.

Comment: If its that important to him, OP can just evaluate the runtime over a subset of all valid inputs